# Web API giving null in response

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, response

I have developed a `web api` which takes two parameters of date time (starting and end), and then should give distinct records.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetMeterPing(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        try
        {


            var startDateTime = start;
            var endDateTime = end;

            var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.sjsj >= startDateTime && m.sjsj <= endDateTime)
                                             .OrderByDescending(o => o.sjsj)
                                             .Select(s => new { s.zdjh, s.sjsj, s.xhqd })
                                             .Distinct()
                                             .FirstOrDefault();                                             


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = result });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

**API URL:**  `http://localhost:14909/api/meters/GetMeterPing/2018-04-28T00:00:00/2018-04-27T23:59:59`

When I run this `web-api` it gives me

> {"data":null}

Also while debugging it the `result` is also `null`

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Obvious question here, but in what universe  is `2018-04-28T00:00:00` before `2018-04-27T23:59:59` ? Or more accurately, how can a date satisfy both of these conditions: `>=  2018-04-28` and `<= 2018-04-27T23:59:59` ?

Comment: ...I didn't look at the order of the dates. That's going to definitely be the root cause of why the Linq query is returning no results.

Comment: @john I'll give the question a point back.   It may seem to be rooted in a fairly simple typographical error,  but it has a clear enough explanation that I don't think it is a bad question. At the very least, it could serve as an example of how you have to be careful when you build such services.  Since the dates, as provided, were nonsensical to the service, the code would benefit from a `BadRequest` being thrown if the dates are flipped. (To some APIs, the dates sent exactly like that would be the way of expressing 'Not In')

Comment: @Alan No, and I didn't downvote it, but it is worth closing because it is a typographical error and not a problem with the code (I also upvoted your answer because simple validation would have prevented this problem).

Comment: @john ...no biggie. It's just that it's only a typographical error within the case he intended. Flipping dates is a way of supporting "Date Not In Range" functionality in an api, so extra validation to add expressiveness to his intenxed meaning is necessary, not just a typo.

Comment: @Alan I see your point. I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Yes, I did a typographical error. But thanks for the support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description of your problem sounds like the Linq query you are executing is not returning any results, so your call to `FirstOrDefault` is defaulting, which is to say it is returning null. You then perform no additional validations, and respond with the result of this line set as the value of an anonymous projection having a `data` property.